# Populate a list adapter by two json urls

Tags: android, json, android-volley

Using volley I successfully display a json url in a listview.Now lets say **url1** `myapi.com/messages`.
I get json array with list of messages but one of the objects is `"id_user_from" : "1"` so to display the name of this user I need to request **url2** `myapi.com/users/id_user=1` 
Here I will get array with all user info including his name which I want to display but I cant request the url2 everytime crashes, 
what I have tried:

- request it inside the first request before adding strings to list
  modle
- request it after the 1st request with another queue
- request it in the adapter class before return view

So please tell me how and where to request the second json url
Here is what its look like 
1st url:

```
{"messages":[{"id_message":"8","id_ad":"14","id_message_parent":"8","id_user_from":"1","id_user_to":"25","message":"\u0634\u0643\u0631\u0627 \u0644\u0643 \u0641\u064a \u0627\u0644\u062d\u0642\u064a\u0642\u0629 \u0645\u062f\u0631\u0643\u064a\u0646 \u0644\u0630\u0644\u0643 \u0644\u0643\u0646 \u0644\u0627 \u064a\u0648\u062c\u062f \u0645\u0648\u0627\u0631\u062f \u0627\u0646\u0647 \u0645\u0634\u0631\u0648\u0639 \u0645\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0635\u0641\u0631 \u0648\u0646\u0633\u0623\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u0648\u0641\u064a\u0642\n\u062a\u062d\u064a\u0627\u062a\u064a","price":"0.000","read_date":null,"created":"2015-11-25 10:01:59","status":"0"},{"id_message":"7","id_ad":"14","id_message_parent":"5","id_user_from":"25","id_user_to":"1","message":"\u062a\u0645\u0646\u064a\u0627\u062a\u064a \u0628\u0627\u0644\u062a\u0648\u0641\u064a\u0642\nUsed\u0645\u0645\u062a\u0627\u0632 \u0644\u0643\u0646 \u064a\u062d\u062a\u0627\u062c \u0644 \u062f\u0639\u0627\u064a\u0629.","price":"0.000","read_date":null,"created":"2015-11-25 00:29:36","status":"0"},{"id_message":"3","id_ad":null,"id_message_parent":"1","id_user_from":"2","id_user_to":"1","message":"jkjhkjhk","price":"0.000","read_date":"2015-11-15 19:53:41","created":"2015-11-14 19:35:43","status":"1"}]}
```

--_------------

2nd url:

```
{"users":[{"id_user":"24","name":"Abo Hasan yaser","seoname":"abo-hasan-yaser","email":"email@hotmail.com","description":null,"status":"1","id_role":"1","id_location":null,"created":"2015-11-24 18:47:50","last_modified":null,"logins":"0","last_login":null,"last_ip":null,"hybridauth_provider_name":null,"subscriber":"1","rate":null,"has_image":"0","failed_attempts":"0","last_failed":null,"notification_date":null,"image":"\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/f5a834abdb228f10408585c45ab9e41e?s=200"}]}
```

Here is a similar code to my code

```
 JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new    JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();



 ////////nigam do you mean request here and getString from where i tried first?//////

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                            movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                            movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                    .doubleValue());
                            movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                            // Genre is json array
                            JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                            ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                            }
                            movie.setGenre(genre);

///i tried to request url2 here////

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();

                }
            });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
```

///and tried here///
    }

Comment: Post the code, it will be helpful.

Comment: Sorry cant know but its a nurmal working volley jsonarrayrequest, the unworking codes dont exist

Comment: Request it after getting response from 1st API call.

Comment: I post a similar code with where i have tried please read it do you mean that?

Comment: That mean, for every json String, you are requesting the url2 API?

Comment: yes for every "id_user_from" : "?" I need to request url2/id_user=? to get his name string

Comment: What the error you got?

Comment: I dont use emulater cuz old pc :/

Comment: You should have tested in device, so you got any exception or not?

Comment: Yes i did, i get app stoped workin

Comment: But, what type of exception, it would be better to help you more.

Comment: I get you, but thats all, just a pop-up says app has stopped

Comment: Can you just plug the device to your system and tell what the exception is coming?

Comment: Unfurtently i cant cuz my app need 4+ android wich i have on a chines taplet no pc software for it

Comment: What about request it befor the first } befor //notifying list adapter?

Comment: @H4F you can try adding your url2 request after `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` line like `AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(url2Req);`

Comment: That is not the case I think, may be its due to for every item in the 1st API calling 2nd API is much more costing, that's why the error is coming.

Comment: oh!! I read your question again..yes,that is not correct approach as suggested in above comment..why don't you just show list with minimum details from first url and then when clicking on listview row should call your url2 showing more details about user.

Comment: DroidwalaI dont thinks thats right cuz i need request for every string from url1

Comment: @nigam, cant agree more, so what about editing the api php to send user name alomg with url1, will that be hard ?

Comment: @droidwala yes that can be done but its uncool when it comes to user friendly ui

Comment: + i will face the same problem in the single message activity

Comment: @H4F If, the API is from your side only, then modify the API to return user details with that API. But, as per the `Droidwala`, if you want, you can use this API.

Comment: I took alook at it, it seems even harder to do so

Comment: API changing is harder or what?

Comment: Yes api change, my site is a modifi of a ready script